# CSS hover transition for another element

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

So this is what I have done, now i need to animate the transition so it pretty much starts at 100x100 and end at 900x300 (widthxheight)

```
<b> title </b>
<ol>
    <li> list </li>
</ol>
```

When I hover over b it shows me the ordered list. All good so far. But I cant seem to get the animation work as I have for all the other elements

```
ol
{   width: 100px; height: 100px;   
transition: all  3s; 
-webkit-transition: all 3s;
}

b.title
{
   background-color: #000000; 
} 

b.title:hover + ol 
{
 width: 925px;
 height: 160px; 
 display: block; 
}
```

How do i fix this? what am i doing wrong?

***I know Using the B tag is not the best, but i was given with this as my only choice.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: chrome, i have transition tags for other browsers as well

Comment: right, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
     <b class="title">title</b>
     <ol>
         <li>List</li>
     </ol>
```

CSS

```
     ol{
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     -webkit-transition: all 3s linear;
     -moz-transition: all 3s linear;
     -o-transition: all 3s linear;
      transition: all 3s linear;
     }

     .title:hover{
     display:block;
     width:925px;
     height:160px;
     }
```

It's good practice to list all the browser prefixes for css3 properties first, and then the actual property.

Answer (score 1):

The transition works if you put the class to the right element.

Change this:

```html
<b> title </b>
```

To this:

```html
<b class="title"> title </b>
```